# How to avoid getting "out of range" IndexError while looping an image and accessing adjacent pixels of a specific coordinate?

Tags: python, image

I'm trying access the adjacent pixels of a specific coordinate when looping a photo in order to get the RGB color but in some cases I get a `IndexError: image index out of range`. I tried avoiding this using some conditionals but didn't work. I would like to know how to prevent this error.

```
img = Image.open('Images/test.jpg')
width, height = img.size
pixel_distance = 1

for x in range(width):
  for y in range(height):

    if y - pixel_distance < 0:
        continue
    if y + pixel_distance < height:
        continue
    if x - pixel_distance < 0:
        continue
    if x + pixel_distance > width:
        continue

    r, g, b = img.getpixel((x, y))  # Center pixel
    r1, g1, b1 = img.getpixel((x, y + pixel_distance))  # Bottom pixel
    r2, g2, b2 = img.getpixel((x, y - pixel_distance))  # Top pixel
    r3, g3, b3 = img.getpixel((x + pixel_distance, y))  # Right pixel
    r4, g4, b4 = img.getpixel((x - pixel_distance, y))  # Left pixel

    r5, g5, b5 = img.getpixel((x + pixel_distance, y + pixel_distance))  # Bottom right pixel
    r6, g6, b6 = img.getpixel((x + pixel_distance, y - pixel_distance))  # Top right pixel
    r7, g7, b7 = img.getpixel((x - pixel_distance, y - pixel_distance))  # Top left pixel
    r8, g8, b8 = img.getpixel((x - pixel_distance, y + pixel_distance))  # Bottom left pixel
```

Comment: What about when x+pixel_distance==width ? and y+pixel_distance==height ? Will it be a valid boundary ? Did you check that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to stop x and y from reaching the outer edges of the image. The size of the image is width by height.
Now obviously x, y must both be larger than 0. Additionally, they should be lower than width and height respectively, BUT remember that in Python, something like X[1:7] includes the first number but not the second.
So x and y must be 2 lower than width and height respectively.
Try the following in place of your conditions:

```
if x and y and x + 1 < width and y + 1 < height:
    # Indent and put in all the image stuff here:
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and it worked out just fine. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change your range statement. if you add 1 to x and x is the maximum value of your array, you are out of range. Maybe you should use a range like: range(1, width-1) . The same for y.

Comment: Thats what the if statements with the continues are for...